# Unable to call a WCF Service with quite-long list of parameters

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm using a WCF perfectly for most of the cases.

When I try to call it with more than a certain number (like 20) of objects in a list (not too complex objects) as a parameter it seems like it can't even reach the service. I'm in debug mode and it doesn't even starts the service execution.

I thought it was because of `MaxArrayLength` and other Service configuration but I have tried everything and anything changed. You can see my Service Configuration in the picture.

[image]

Do you have any suggestion?? Should I change anything in my client configuration???

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you combine all the parameters into a single object instead?

Comment: Can you confirm that it works with less objects (e.g. <20) and doesn't work with more, **without** any other changes in your code? You might have changed something else as well between the two tests. Just to make sure. (In itself, especially if the objects are homogeneous in their serialized size, the assumed cause of the problem does not sound too likely.)

Comment: well... I've not tried it @mellamokb, do you think it matters if you send an object with 20 strings or a list of 20 strings?? It would be quite difficult to search inside but I can try it if it can change thinks ;)

Comment: Yes @ThomasCalc, it is working perfectly with less than 20 objects but it crashes with bigger tests (40, 50...). I don't know the exact number where it stops working...

Comment: *"it seems like it can't even reach the service"* - can you [Fiddle](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) it and see what the actual error is?

Comment: Oh my god, forgot about look in Fiddler!!! Thanks @SliverNinja I'll take a look and tell you what was happening (now I'm away from work...)

Comment: Might be worth having a quick look in the event viewer as well, in case anything's being logged in there that'll give you a quick clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely you haven't set a higher value for the `maxItemsInObjectGraph` for `DataContractSerializer`.

```
<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.maxitemsinobjectgraph.aspx

Comment: The default value is [pretty large](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx)

Comment: I thought it would be a lesser value like other settings. Thanks for pointing that :)

Comment: By the way I referred this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058202/wcf-service-datacontractserializer-maxitemsinobjectgraph-in-web-config

Comment: You may yet be right - the OP might have configured the value to a much lower value than the default.